# preg_replace If result replace or not replace . show only replaced text otherwise blank

Tags: php

i want to get preg_replace If replace then show result otherwise blank

```
<?php
 $text = "text4 text1 text2 text3";
 $replace = [
 '/\btext1\b/'         => 'replace1', //replace case sensitive
 '/\btext2\b/i'         => 'replace2', //non-sensitive
 '/\b(text3|text4)\b/i' => 'replace3', //replace both text3 and text4
 ];
$result = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);

echo $result;
```

> Result = replace3 replace1 replace2 replace3

And

```
<?php
 $text = "text4x text1x text2x text3x";
 $replace = [
 '/\btext1\b/'         => 'replace1', //replace case sensitive
 '/\btext2\b/i'         => 'replace2', //non-sensitive
 '/\b(text3|text4)\b/i' => 'replace3', //replace both text3 and text4
 ];
$result = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);

echo $result;
```

> Result = text4x text1x text2x text3x

if not replace anything then its showing orginal $text , I want to show there Blank result if  any word not replace

Comment: By saying 'if result found', do you mean that if a replace has taken palce or not?

Comment: if not replace anything then its showing orginal $text , I want to show there Blank result if  any word not replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcmp to compare strings.

strcmp($text,$result); // will return 0 if the strings are the same

```
$compare = strcmp($text,$result);
if($compare == 0){ echo $text;  }
else { echo 'Result not found'; }
```

Comment: Bro maybe my coding also have problem .   `$text = "text4 text1 text2x text3x";` then result is `replace3 replace1 text2x text3x` there is two original word , i want to show only replace text . is it possible ?

Comment: $after1 = explode(" ",$result);
$after2 = explode(" ",$text);
$result2=array_diff($after1,$after2);
print_r($result2);
This is what I have at the moment- explode $result and $text (by blank space), and then get the difference of those 2 arrays (this gives you replace3 replace1)

Comment: Thanks bro .  Is theare any option to get result in normal value . not array